# React testing library - how to get all instances of rendered components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to get an access to all components that were rendered in the test. I need it, to read the props of those components.

Consider a ui with checkboxes. Each checkbox can be: checked/unchecked, have some background color and a dynamic size. It doesn't make sense to add `data-testid` attribute to the dom nodes just to check if they are rendered correctly. I would end up with a lot of `data-testid` attributes, like:

```
data-testid="green-checked-12"
data-testid="green-checked-8"
data-testid="green-unchecked-10"
data-testid="blue-checked-16"
data-testid="yellow-unchecked-8"
...etc
```

Ideally I would like to get all instances of Checkbox component and check the props:

```
test("Checkbox", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    render(<Checkbox />);

    const checkboxComponents = findComponent(Checkbox); // unfortunately there is no such function exposed by testing-library

    expect(checkboxComponents).toEqual([
      { color: "green", checked: true, size: 12 },
      { color: "green", checked: true, size: 8 },
      { color: "green", checked: false, size: 10 },
      { color: "blue", checked: true, size: 16 },
      { color: "yellow", checked: false, size: 8 }
    ]);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if that's possible with react-testing library, or if there is any way to traverse the tree myself and check it.

Comment: When you do the find you already get all elements. Can't you iterate on that and check for each one?

Comment: do you mean `findComponent` function? It doesn't exist tho. The snippet describes ideally api.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your `<Checkbox />` component renders an `<input type="checkbox" />`. If yes, then :

```js
getAllByRole('checkbox')
```

might be what you're looking for.

Then, instead of checking what props are passed to your component (which is actually useless because you want to test your UI, not whether `React` works correctly or not) you can use [toBeChecked](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobechecked) from [testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) to verify whether a specific checkbox is checked or not, and [toHaveStyle](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle) for the styling :

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';

...

const checkboxes = screen.getAllByRole('checkbox');
expect(checkboxes[0]).toBeChecked();
expect(checkboxes[0]).toHaveStyle(`
  background-color: *your_value*;
  width: *your_value*;
  height: *your_value*;
`);
```

NB : you will have to add [testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) to your node modules if it not already the case.

Comment: Thanks, that looks cool. But still not sure how to test for correct color and size :(

Comment: You can use `toHaveStyle` function for testing the styling of a component, I've updated the answer according to that :)

Comment: @feerlay You might pay attention what library you use for your css styles. In example of emotion, depending how you pass your css props, you test will pass or fail against style assertations.

Comment: @aquinq thanks, this looks interesting. The only downside I see is that I already have a test for Checkbox component that look exactly the same as in your answer. So now, I'm just repeating this test in a view that uses Checkbox component, instead of checking whether it got "called" with correct props.